# Matlab,problem with concatenation in an iteration? How do I fix it?

Tags: matlab, iteration, static-text

The problem I have is that it only works partially, but what can I add to make it work?

```
A2 = [20 4 6 8 5];
A3 = [10 2 3 4 6];
Str=[];
formatSpec = 'P%d (%d,%d)';
for i=1:length(A2)
    str = char(sprintf (formatSpec, i, A2(i),A3(i)));
    Str=[Str;str];
end
set(handles.text2,'string',Str);
```

Comment: what do you mean it only works "partially". Please explain your problem in detail.

Comment: for example, if one of the matrices has [2 4 6] and the other matrix has [10 20 30], it works there, but when I put a two-digit number in any of the matrices I get a vertcat error,How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not concatenating strings but char-arrays. Thinking it this way, it already answers your question: If you have a two-digit number, the char-array is one element longer than the char-array of a single-digit number... and you cannot concatenate two arrays of different size vertically.

The solution is fairly simple: use actual strings (introduced somewhere around R2016a). Strings are indicated with `""` instead of `''`, which are chars. So replace your `char`with `string` and it works fine. (Even better: provide the `formatSpec`as `""`-string and it `sprintf()` will return a string right away)

*Side note:*

BTW, you should always allocate memory if your are looping. That is why the `Str` has an orange squiggly underline. This is because MATLAB stores arrays in RAM contiguously and has to copy it to a larger section it it outgrows the current one.
So instead of `Str=[]`, write `Str = strings(length(A2),1)`, and index `Str(i) = ...` in the loop.

Personally, I like `num2str` more that `sprintf` but I cannot give a good reason for this, except for that it also works without providing a format.

Comment: excuse my english, use the translator

Comment: try to answer, but in the end delete what you said, it was an error, I hope that what you delete is not published, but almost everything you said served me, only that Str = strings (length (A2), 1). I did not understand this part already but if I use the rest that he told me

Comment: @Andre3600 you should tell MATLAB beforehand how many strings you will place in the vector. As you loop suggests, it is `length(A2)` strings, so you can allocate them.